# discord bot python running a task while waiting for user response?

Tags: discord.py

I was wondering if there's a way to run a task as I wait for a user's message or reaction. I plan on making a game command where a blurred image slowly gets less blurrier and the players have to be the first one to guess what the image is showing before it's completely visible, however the wait_for coroutine forces me to wait for a message which makes me unable to decrease the blur on the image until a player guesses what it is.

Comment: Have you tried anything? It's recommended to provide [a minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). SO is not a site for us to write code for you, it's to help you improve code you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`client.loop.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop) to asynchronously run a function.

---

```py
async def makeLessBlurry(interval):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(interval)
        # run your code to make image less blurry
        # break and return if finished

# Your command function, depending of what you use (ext or not) this will look different
async def guessImage():
    # Start showing image...

    client.loop.create_task(makeLessBlurry(1))

    def check(): 
        # Define your own check method if needed

    await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
```